# Where can I find airfoil data for the Beechcraft 1900D tail?

Tags: airfoil, tail, beechcraft-1900

I am creating a CAD model of Beechcraft 1900D from images for a project. So far most info is available in http://www.users.on.net/~grypen/b1900d.html except the airfoil used by the tails. I have searched extensively and wasn't able to come up with any data. I am new to this and may be unaware of popular sites for these kinds of data. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!